# Socket instance wont connect to local server

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm new to socket programming/networking in general. I'm trying to create a simple IRC that's an echo server. I'm using 127.0.0.1 and port 8080 for my socket object but I keep getting a ConnectionException. Does it have to do with me not setting anything up on my computer to allow connections?

Client class (I need to make a Server class maybe that handles allowing connections?)

```java
package client.build;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    private static Socket socket;
    private static DataInputStream inputStream;
    private static DataOutputStream outputStream;
    // This might not be needed
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private final String[] arguments;

    public Client(String[] arguments) throws IOException {
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    public void connect() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
        socket = new Socket(arguments[0], Integer.parseInt(arguments[1]));
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch(ConnectException e) {
            System.out.println("failed to connect to echo server");
            Thread.sleep(600);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

- You are trying to create echo server, which means that you need to listen on 8080 instead of connecting to 8080?

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

- Assuming that your code is actually the IRC client. Do you have something that listens on port 8080 on 127.0.0.1? Try using `netstat` to verify that it is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
- Check that `arguments[0]` is really 127.0.0.1. You can try with the `null` for [localhost](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int))